# Why am I getting an iOS build error in EXPO?

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo

I try to build applications using expo build: ios, I enter the apple id data, but in response I get an error:
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
502 Bad Gateway

[image: snapshot]

```
expo diagnostics

root@66970:/home/dev/app/learnfast# expo diagnostics


Expo CLI 3.18.2 environment info:
System:
OS: Linux 4.9 Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) 9 (stretch)
Shell: 4.4.12 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
Node: 13.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
npm: 6.14.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
npmPackages:
expo: ~37.0.3 => 37.0.7
react: ~16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz => 0.61.4
npmGlobalPackages:
expo-cli: 3.18.2
```

Comment: is your apple account paid one?

Comment: Yes, I’m a member of the Apple Developer Program. 99 USD per membership year

Comment: Successfully logging in via the web https://developer.apple.com/